# Extracting an xtabs subarray from an array given condition in R

Tags: r, arrays, xtabs

There is a 2-way table which is an array from `xtabs()`, like this:

```
    A  B
12  0  0
20  1  0
41 22 16
49  4  8
50  0  1
56  3  2
57  4  2
59  1  0
63  0  3
64  2  1
65  0  0
68  0  1
71  2  7
72  2  1
73  9  7
78  0  1
```

How can one extract a subtable such that each cell must be 2 or greater? The resulting table would look like this:

```
    A  B
41 22 16
49  4  8
56  3  2
57  4  2
71  2  7
73  9  7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter it like you would any other matrix.

```r
tab[rowSums(tab < 2) == 0,]
#     A  B
# 41 22 16
# 49  4  8
# 56  3  2
# 57  4  2
# 71  2  7
# 73  9  7
```

---

Data

```r
tab <- structure(c(0L, 1L, 22L, 4L, 0L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 16L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L), dim = c(16L, 2L), dimnames = list(c("12", "20", "41", "49", "50", "56", "57", "59", "63", "64", "65", "68", "71", "72", "73", "78"), c("A", "B")), class = c("xtabs", "table"))
```

Comment: Thanks [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)! I had a similar solution but this works only for r x 2 tables, right? That I did not like. So, could the general solution be `tab[rowSums(tab < dim(tab)[2]) == 0,]`?

Comment: That logic is different than in your question. You said *"each cell must be 2 or greater"*, which is where the `2` in my answer comes from. In my (limited) understand, that `2` is not the same as `ncol(tab)` (which is also 2, but only coincidentally). If you have 17 columns and you want rows where all cells in that row are 2 or greater, then my code (`tab[rowSums(tab < 2) == 0,]`) remains unchanged.

Comment: Oh, I see now... `rowSums()` misled me. It automatically converts booleans to integers, and only if both are FALSE (0) than the condition hold. Sorry. Great stuff. Thanks [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans)!

Comment: yes, R silently casts ... so `sum(c(T,F,T))` sums to 2. Glad it helps!